# Issue with Minecraft 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

Minecraft freezes my entire laptop when i press ANY media keys in full screen mode. Not sure if its a Minecraft glitch or something not configured correctly in my OS. Also having random screen flickering and very low FPS, seems locked at 60 FPS......on windows 7 with same laptop, i got around 260-300 FPS.

Here's my specs:

(Intel core i5-2430M CPU @2.40GHz)

(Intel Sandybridge Mobile Graphics)

(64 bit Ubuntu 15.10(updated)

(8 GB RAM)

(using default window manager)

(using the following Intel Drivers https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0)

Comment: vsync off for the fps part?...

Comment: @wagyourtail yeah.....vsync on or off....it strangely doesn't make a difference, its capped at 60fps.....and also Optifine doesn't make ANY difference either! This is with all MC settings on low.....Smooth lighting off ETC.

Comment: try running `java -version` and post the results

Comment: @wagyourtail java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)